# SQL Table -- How to write a query to determine whether a team has scored more points in the first half or second half of the year

Tags: mysql

My data contains the statistics of 100 British football teams. The attributes of the table are :

```
(Team Name, TeamTown, Status_Professional/Amateur, YearTeamFounded, ChairmanOfTeam, TeamRevenue, DateOfGames, PointsScoredByTeam).
```

Let me show you TWO rows out of hundreds of rows in my project:

```
(LiverpoolFC, Liverpool, Professional, 1892, Tom Werner, £100million, 2013-12-25, 5)
(LiverpoolFC, Liverpool, Professional, 1892, Tom Werner, £100million, 2013-04-12, 1)
```

These are just TWO rows pertaining to Liverpool that I am showing you, the reality is that there are 17 rows with the name "Liverpool" in it. My task to to determine (from the 17 rows) whether Liverpool Football Club scored more goals in the FIRST HALF of 2013 or the SECOND HALF of 2013. What I FAIL to understand is how you can separate the two halves. A year is a "DATE" in SQL, not an "INT". That is what is troubling me. From the short example I have given you, it is clear that Liverpool scored more goals in the second half of 2013. But how do you actually write a query to show this (and remember, I have 17 rows to deal with, not two)? Please can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Use a where `where DateOfGames between '2013-01-01' and '2013-06-01'` or something of that sort. Then do the same for the second half of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(DateOfGames <= '2013-06-30', PointsScoredByTeam, 0)) AS `first_half_points`,
    SUM(IF(DateOfGames > '2013-06-30', PointsScoredByTeam, 0)) AS `second_half_points`
FROM yourTable
WHERE `Team Name` = 'LiverpoolFC'
    AND DateOfGames >= '2013-01-01'
    AND DateOfGames < '2014-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show the points gained on the first half of the year and the points gained on the second half:

```
SELECT
  TeamName,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Month(DateOfGames)<=6 THEN PointsScoredByTeam END) FirstHalf,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Month(DateOfGames)>7 THEN PointsScoredByTeam END) SecondHalf
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  DateOfGames>='2013-01-01'
  AND DateOfGames<'2014-01-01'
GROUP BY
  TeamName
```

Comment: fthiella, I'm very grateful for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
SELECT
    SUM(MONTH(DateOfGames) <= 6)) firstHalf,
    SUM(MONTH(DateOfGames) >= 7)) secondHalf
FROM table
WHERE TeamName = 'LiverpoolFC' AND YEAR(DateOfGames) = 2013
```

Bear in mind that in MySQL `true` is synonym of `1` as well as a `false` is synonym of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you gotta have a criteria to use and judge when a given date happens to be on the first or second half. In this case you could consider the first 6 months to be on the first half, and the remaining months as being on the second half.

Second step is to use this criteria to group and sum the actual points per half for that specific team.

```
SELECT YEAR(DateOfGames) YEAR, 
       CASE WHEN MONTH(DateOfGames) <= 6 
            THEN 'First Half' 
            ELSE 'Second Half' 
       END HALF,
       SUM(PointsScoredByTeam) POINTS_PER_HALF
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE TeamName = 'LiverpoolFC'
 GROUP BY YEAR(DateOfGames),
          CASE WHEN MONTH(DateOfGames) <= 6 
               THEN 'First Half' 
               ELSE 'Second Half' 
           END HALF,
```

Comment: Mt. Schneiders, yes, your code works. Thanks for taking the time to write it out. Much appreciated.